# FragmentActivity: Where to register receivers, open databases

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-fragmentactivity

I have a FragmentActivity with different Fragments as Tabs.

One Tab needs to listen to a BroadcastReceiver. Should I register/unregister the receiver in the Fragment or in the inherent FragmentActivity.

Another Tab works with a database. Same question: Where to open/close the database?

Also: what are the appropriate methods? onResume() for registering and opening and onPause() for unregistering and closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your BroadcastReceivers in the onAttach(Activity) method in the Fragments and unregister them in the onDetach(). For database it's probably wise to use ContentProviders and the LoaderManager (SupportLoaderManager in case you're using the support library).